# Testing a random transaction_id in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm building an API POST call that includes data to be sent in the call. One piece of that data is a transaction_id, which I'm creating using the following code:

```
transaction_id = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[0..10].to_i(16).to_s(10)
```

I'm also using RSpec 2.12.2, which doesn't have `allow` defined yet, so I can't do or even test something like

```
allow(Digest::SHA1).to receive(:hexdigest).and_return("transaction_id")
```

How can I mock a transaction_id in RSpec? I can freeze time, but having the rand in `[Time.now, rand]` returns different results even if time is frozen.

Comment: Digest::SHA1.stub(:hexdigest).and_return(transaction_id)

Comment: This returns: `undefined method 'stub' for Digest::SHA1:Class`

Comment: OOps try:   Digest::SHA1.any_instance.stub(:hexdigest).and_return(transaction_id)

Comment: Returns a new error:  `undefined method 'stub' for #<Mocha::ClassMethods::AnyInstance:0x007fe317354600>`   Mocha is in my gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
Digest::SHA1.any_instance.stubs(:hexdigest).returns("transaction_id")
```

based on examples here:  https://github.com/freerange/mocha